# Access computer hardware using applet in web browser

Tags: java, applet

I have a Web Application that connects to a hardware/computer resource by using Active X control. But I need to remove the Active X control and use some other means to communicate with the hardware.

After doing research I got to know it is possible by using Java Applet, Flash Player and Silver lite . But in many of the forums are suggesting to use Java Applet. I am not able to find much information how it can be achieved using Java Applet.I am actually a novice in developing java application so I request some assistance or maybe some links which helps in implementation using applet.

regards, Sid

Comment: That sounds dodgy. Why do you need direct access to the hardware? More specifically... What hardware?

Comment: Don't investigate Java Applets for new application. Rather have a look at [Java™ Web Start](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/)

Comment: I have an existing web application which connects to a hardware(Ex: Scanner) using active X controls . I want to replace Active X control with Java applet to communicate with my hardware.

Comment: Applets are or will be deprecated (https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free) You could use webstart as suggested above. Personally I wrote an java applet once which accessed some hardware device which is still working perfectly. I used JNA to access a *.dll or *.so file...